# Unable to get 'text-overflow: ellipsis' to work with two adjacent span elements

Tags: html, css

I have been attempting to get ellipsis to appear when text is two long, on two spans that are next to each other using `display: inline-block`:

[image: CSS text-overflow not working properly]

Here is the simplified CSS in a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/IQAndreas/fffo84nq/1/

In fact, I can't even `overflow: none` to show up properly. Those two `span` elements have given me nothing but trouble.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid hard-coding the values `240px` and `40px` too much; I don't want to have to edit 60 different lines of code if I want to move something a few pixels to the left or right.

Comment: Just use overflow on `menu-element` https://jsfiddle.net/fffo84nq/2/

Comment: @NenadVracar You are a god among men.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add those style to `menu-element`

```
.menu-element {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
  overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fffo84nq/3/)

Comment: That works. Is there any way for me to still keep the `[edit]` button to the right of the text, even if I am using ellipses?

Answer (score -1):

Need to specify width for `ellipsis` to work

```
#palette-menu .palette-name {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;

    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

   display: inline-block;
    width: 66%;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fffo84nq/5/)**

Comment: Now you messed up the alignment of the text. It's now in the top left corner instead of centered beside the color (I have been pulling my hair out over the exact same problems all day)